# Can we get a lite version of chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

Current chat is gorgeous, but I want a minimalistic experience. No animations, no avatars, no stars or favorites, no sounds -- just chat and user list.

Could we get an option to switch between full and lite versions of chat?

Comment: We have a chat?

Comment: @Lord it's in beta preview this weekend: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/third-place-chat-beta-preview/

Comment: @Jared: I need to start following that blog... seems all of my "We have X?!" questions are answered by "Yes, its on [blog link]." Anyway, thanks for that link

Comment: @Lord There was a [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57017/feedback-wanted-three-day-test-run-of-the-chat) about it too, but it's easy to miss :)

Comment: There is `?mobile=true` - any use?

Answer (score 5):

["How quickly the world owes him something he knew existed only ten seconds ago..."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itn8TwFCO4M)

Comment: You sir, owe me a new keyboard.

Comment: (video now deleted)

Comment: @Marc I've fixed the link.  To future viewers, if the video disappears again, search for "Louis C.K. talks on Conan O'brien about technology" to find it elsewhere. Great video.

Answer (score 2):

There is a now mobile version of chat for iPhone / Android that works quite well in our testing.

Comment: Windows Phone 7?

Comment: Should work, try it.. but we pretend anything pre-Mango (IE9 mobile) doesn't exist. IE 7.5 on a phone.. brrrr.. nasty