# Chat layout/CSS problem with iPhone/iPad Safari

Tags: bug, chat, iphone, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Can we get a lite version of chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57169/can-we-get-a-lite-version-of-chat)

I thought I'd login to see what chat looked like on my iPhone this morning. Unfortunately, it's pretty much unusable. The right pane and the chat bar scroll upwards; they're not fixed in position. If you want to type something you have to scroll right up to the top, type it and then scroll right back down again.

[image]

It was tested on iPad simulator, and it had the same issue there.

Comment: yerp its a known issue, there will be an iphone skin comming soon